# How do you derive that $v= 2W/QI$?

Tags: electrons, mass, electric-current, charge, work

I was searching for the derivation of the mass by charge ratio of the electron and found this as part of it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here $N=$ no. of electrons, $v$ is the velocity of the electron, $W$ is the work done in the motion of the electron, $Q$ is the charge on the electrode and I is the current.

So, in this derivation I did understand most of it except the $v=2W/QI$ part. So, how do you derive $v=2W/QI$?

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $v=\frac{2W}{QI}$ doesn't seem right, the dimensions of the sides don't match.  velocity is metres per second that can't be got from the right hand side.  Even if it meant $v=\frac{2W}{Q}\times I$, something is still not right, so best to check everything.

Also check if there is another v, a capital $V$ that means voltage, perhaps the two vs have been mixed up somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, your explanation seems right. $I$ is supposed to be H (magnetic field) and the radius of cuvature. I supposed it was current though. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, it's traditional to up-vote or tick an answer that was helpful!

Comment: Thank you Fellow!